# MariaDB Query is way too slow

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

today I ran into a performance issue with a MariaDB query for this scenario:
I have a table called stations where gas stations are saved (around 17k entries) with post_code, uuid, name, and other info that aren't used in this case.
Then there's another table called prices (~210Mio entries) where a single entry represents a single price change for a single station with its specific date time and station_uuid.

First I needed to retrieve the min price for diesel in a 30-minute interval of a single day. This works fine. But then I needed to add the corresponding stations' names of the station the price change happened. So I added the specific join Logic but then remembered that it's not guaranteed to use the correct station name when grouping by time. So I tried to use a subquery but that's resulting in a timeout error.

I'm using single-column BTREE indexes on prices.diesel, prices.date, stations.post_code.

Here are my so far tried SQL Queries:

1. Without name:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(diesel) AS "Minimal",
  date - interval minute(date)%30 minute AS time
FROM prices 
LEFT JOIN stations
  ON prices.station_uuid = stations.uuid
WHERE `date` BETWEEN (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1684627200)) AND (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1684713599)) 
    AND diesel > 0.0 
    AND post_code = 59929
GROUP BY date_format(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i');
```

2. With name:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(diesel) AS "Minimal",
  name AS "Tankstelle"
  date - interval minute(date)%30 minute AS time
FROM prices 
LEFT JOIN stations
  ON prices.station_uuid = stations.uuid
WHERE `date` BETWEEN (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1684627200)) AND (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1684713599)) 
    AND diesel > 0.0 
    AND post_code = 33106
GROUP BY date_format(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i');
```

3. With Subquery:

```
SELECT 
  stations.name AS "Tankstelle",
  date - interval minute(date)%30 minute as time
FROM prices 
LEFT JOIN stations
  ON prices.station_uuid = stations.uuid
WHERE `date` BETWEEN (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1684627200)) AND (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1684713599)) 
    AND diesel > 0.0 
    AND post_code = 59929
    AND diesel = (
      SELECT MIN(diesel) as Min 
      FROM prices p
      WHERE p.date BETWEEN (prices.date - interval minute(prices.date)%30 minute) AND (prices.date - interval ((minute(prices.date)%30)+30) minute))
```

EDIT to answer first three comments (23.05.2023):

MariaDB version: `10.11.3-MariaDB-1:10.11.3+maria~ubu2204`

"diesel" is the price of diesel but if it is a change for e10 then the diesel will be 0 so to avoid using those rows I filter for 0 values

May sound a bit ignorant, but I don't know exactly how "with ties" works, so I don't have an opinion yet. And the clustered key is the primary key, isn't it? If yes it should be answered with the table definitions. If not then it sounds even more ignorant since you would need to explain to me how it differs from the primary key.

Thanks for the help in advance.

The result of EXPLAIN is the following:

Query 1:

```
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                          | rows   | Extra                                                               |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | prices   | range  | date,diesel       | date    | 5       | NULL                         | 695600 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | stations | eq_ref | PRIMARY,post_code | PRIMARY | 16      | tankonix.prices.station_uuid | 1      | Using where                                                         |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Query 2:

```
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                          | rows   | Extra                                                               |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | prices   | range  | date,diesel       | date    | 5       | NULL                         | 695600 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | stations | eq_ref | PRIMARY,post_code | PRIMARY | 16      | tankonix.prices.station_uuid | 1      | Using where                                                         |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Query 3:
[explain result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Egk.png)

```
+------+--------------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+-----------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table    | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                          | rows      | Extra                              |
+------+--------------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+-----------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | prices   | range  | date,diesel       | date    | 5       | NULL                         | 695600    | Using index condition; Using where |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | stations | eq_ref | PRIMARY,post_code | PRIMARY | 16      | tankonix.prices.station_uuid | 1         | Using where                        |
|    4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p        | ALL    | date              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                         | 207323157 | Using where                        |
+------+--------------------+----------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+-----------+------------------------------------+
```

My Table Definitions:

prices:
[table prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yftvD.png)
[indexes prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLcVH.png)

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table



                                                     |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| prices | CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `station_uuid` text NOT NULL,
  `diesel` float NOT NULL,
  `e10` float NOT NULL,
  `e5` float NOT NULL,
  `dieselchange` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `e5change` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `e10change` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`) USING HASH,
  KEY `e5` (`e5`),
  KEY `e10` (`e10`),
  KEY `diesel` (`diesel`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=381367318 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

stations:
[table stations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5xw6.png) [indexes stations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12GGb.png)

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table




                    |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| stations | CREATE TABLE `stations` (
  `uuid` uuid NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  `house_number` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `openingtimes_json` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`openingtimes_json`)),
  `first_active` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
  KEY `post_code` (`post_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT (09.06.2023):

I succeeded in Optimizing it enough. First I completed the steps mentioned in the marked answer, then it went much better but not fast enough so I proceeded to try different approaches and succeeded with:

```
SELECT 
  stations.name AS "Tankstelle",
  date - interval minute(date)%30 minute as time_begin,
  date - interval minute(date)%30 - 30 minute as time_end
FROM stations 
JOIN prices
  ON prices.station_uuid = stations.uuid
JOIN (SELECT MIN(diesel) as price,
        date_format(date - interval minute(date)%30 minute, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:59") as time
      FROM prices p
      JOIN stations
        ON stations.uuid = p.station_uuid
      WHERE p.date BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1684627200) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1684713599)
        AND diesel > 0
        AND stations.post_code = 59929
      GROUP BY date_format(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) as min
    ON min.time Between (date - interval minute(date)%30 minute) and (date - interval minute(date)%30 - 30 minute)
WHERE `date` BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1684627200) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1684713599)
    AND diesel > 0.0 
    AND post_code = 59929;
```

like this it gives me the name of the station corresponding to the cheapest diesel price in the given city grouped for each half an hour.

Comment: is diesel the diesel price or diesel variation of price? I believe it's the price but the clause diesel > 0.0 doesn't make sense if so.. :/ but you also talk about "the price change happened", where are you seeing this change?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? And what is your clustering key on `prices`? From what I can tell the index that will benefit the most is a composite index on (`date`, `diesel`, `station_uuid`) - This would also make a very good candidate for a clustering key (if it isn't already) assuming all (or almost all) records are inserted chronologically. Finally, how do you want to deal with ties?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: See the tag I added.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to answer all your Questions. If you need more Information I will do my best to provide. Thanks for the flag @RickJames I didn't know this flag existed.

Comment: @GarethD - When designing a composite index, put `date` _last_.  The utility of a composite index stops with any column that is used in a "range" test.

Comment: @Atronix  Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE prices; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE stations; and  EVERY EXPLAIN needs the QUERY that was used EXPLAIN SELECT (rest of your query); for analysis.   In MYSQL using ONLY single column indexes are of NO VALUE when you need specific COLumns in ORDER of WHERE selection for performance improvement.

Comment: @RickJames The idea of the composite index was more so that the `station_uuid` and `diesel` columns would be within the date index, as based on the cardinalities in the table this is the key index to speed up the query in question. Once the date filter is applied there should be only a workable number of rows left, as long as bookmark lookups are not required. If non key columns were a feature in MySQL I would have suggested them. While I am no expert with MySQL, this index would certainly be useful in other engines, and seems to be used in [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/0akeWgKe)

Comment: @GarethD - Cardinalities are irrelevant.  `=` tests must come before range tests, such as `BETWEEN` and `>0`.  Else they won't be looked at.

Comment: @GarethD - Imagine concatenating the index columns together, then making that the index key.

Comment: I'd admittedly missed the equality check on post code, but even this should mean the better key is `(station_uuid, date, diesel)` and not `(station__uuid, diesel, date)`? `diesel` does not form any part of any filtering, only part of a sort, so it would make no sense (to me at least) to have this before date in the index. As far as I can tell, when given the choice of the two MySQL is opting for the one with date before diesel, rather than date after - https://dbfiddle.uk/nRSFWWsi

Comment: @WilsonHauck with TEXT results u mean no Screenshots? The explain statement should be in my post as Screenshot, if you want it as Text not Screenshot i would need to add.

Comment: @Atronix Yes, no screenshot always preferred.  You have 3 queries listed and 1 EXPLAIN, what was the QUERY used to get the EXPLAIN report?  We still do not see SHOW CREATE TABLE prices; or SHOW CREATE TABLE stations;  The tables could have been changed multiple times during this effort to improve performance.

Comment: You have a `LEFT JOIN` from `stations`, implying that the row might be missing.  This would prevent making use of `station_uuid` to reach into `prices`.  Also, using the `WHERE` conditions in the index is much preferred.   Cf [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Thanks for the CREATEs, etc; I added a lot to my Answer.  I added the CREATEs from the dbfiddle so I could see what to say.  Caveat:  I addressed only the one query with sufficient details.

Comment: Screenshots are often hard to read and prevent machine analysis of the text.

Comment: Rather than that kludge for generating 100K rows, see the pseudo table `seq_1_to_100000`; it's a beautiful feature of MariaDB.  (I see that the dbfiddle used MariaDB; alas, MySQL does not have the equivalent.)

Comment: Thanks i will try your stuff. And about the Rest @WilsonHauck i will update my post and add the Text stuff. I just thought the Text variant is even less readable, but i think you guys just know how to read it and i dont.

Comment: @RickJames I just added the text parts of the explains and show create tables.

Comment: In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` _is_ clustered with the data and is "unique" and is an index.

Comment: "with ties" -- Are you referring to @GarethD comment?  Where the 3 columns `(date, diesel, station_uuid)` might be the same for multiple rows.

Comment: What do you expect from KEY date (date) USING HASH ? I have not read about this option.

Comment: @RickJames yes I was referring to GarethD. KEY is that what is being created when Using `ALTER TABLE [COLUMN] ADD INDEX([COLUMN]);` So it is the index.

Comment: You clarified that you are using MariaDB 10.11, not MySQL. Keep in mind that although MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, both products have changed a lot since then, with little regard to continuing compatibility. You should now consider MariaDB as a totally different product, not "a type of MySQL." Solutions for MySQL won't necessarily work for MariaDB, nor vice versa. I edited the above to make it clear you are using MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BETWEEN  (  SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(1684627200) )  AND ...
```

-->

```
BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1684627200) AND ...
```

That is, simply use the expression; you don't need to `SELECT` it.

Since the `WHERE` clause tests columns from different tables, the Optimizer will pick one of the tables (`p` vs `s`) to start with.  It may goof.

Since there is a test on `s.PostCode` in the `WHERE`, the `LEFT JOIN` is really a `JOIN`.  Please change that to help humans read the query.  Being a JOIN opens the possibility of starting with `s` instead of being forced to start with `p`.

```
            FROM  prices AS p
            JOIN  stations AS s  ON s.uuid = p.station_uuid
            WHERE  p.date BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1684627200)
                              AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1684713599)
              AND  p.diesel > 0.0
              AND  s.post_code = 1
```

Starting with s:

```
s: (you effectively have this)
   INDEX(post_code,       -- because of =
         uuid)            -- for "covering"
p: (you have this)
   INDEX(station_uuid,    -- =
         date,            -- assuming it is more selective than diesel
         diesel)          -- covering
```

Starting with p:

```
p: INDEX(date, diesel, station_uuid)  -- covering, but otherwise unexciting
s: the PRIMARY KEY(uuid) will be used effectively.
```

Recommendation (after changing to `JOIN`): the second `p` index.

Notes:

- The Optimizer will pick between starting with `s` and `p` depending on crude statistics it has.
- Each secondary index implicitly includes a copy of the `PRIMARY KEY` (so it can get to the rest of the rows).  Hence `(post_code, uuid)` is the same as `(post_code)`, which you already have.
- I have not found that `OVER(PARTITION BY...)` has any magical performance, so I worry that *that* will be the slowest part of the query.
- My [*Groupwise-Max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) found that it is not the fastest, but does avoid showing duplicates, which the Uncorrelated Subquery suffers from.

Comment: @GarethD - I addressed some of your concerns in the edit here.

Comment: I corrected the column names in your stuff. I hope that was ok.